# Why the query from controller not display in table using ajax in Laravel?

Tags: ajax, laravel-5, html-table

I want to create a searching filters and display the output using ajax.

This is the button for submit the data:

```
   {!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'action' => 'Modul\CarianAnugerahController@search']) !!}

   //Form for filter here...

   {{ Form::submit('Cari', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'id' =>'search']) }}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

This is the output table under the form:

```
  <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">Senarai Calon Anugerah</div>
                     <div class="panel-body">
                            @if (session('status'))
                                <div class="alert alert-success">
                                    {{ session('status') }}
                                </div>
                            @endif


                             @if(Auth::check())
                                <div class="container table-responsive col-lg-12">
                                    <!-- <div class="container text-center"> -->      
                                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="calon_table" >
                                            <thead>
                                              <tr>
                                                <td class="text-center col-lg-3"><strong>Name</strong></td>
                                                <td class="text-center"><strong>Action</strong></td>
                                                <!-- <td class="text-center"><strong>Lihat Rekod</strong></td> -->
                                              </tr>
                                            </thead>

                                        <tbody id="calon_anugerah">

                                        </tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    <!-- </div> -->

                                </div>
                            @endif
                            @if(Auth::guest())
                                <a href="/login" class="btn btn-info"> Anda perlu log masuk.</a>
                            @endif
                     </div>
                  </div>
    </div>
```

The ajax code to get the data is:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $('#search').on('click', function(){

    $.get("{{ URL::to('search-calon') }}",function(data){

        $.each(data, function(i, value){

            var tr =$("<tr/>");
              tr.append($("<td/>",{
                  text : value.name
              }))
              $('#calon_anugerah').append(tr);
        });
    })
  })
</script>
```

I had queried the data using the code in CarianAnugerahController@search:

```
 $query = DB::table('itemregistrations')
    ->select('itemregistrations.ItemRegistrationID','itemregistrations.name', 'itemregistrations.Nobadan');

    if(request('umur')) {
        $query->whereRaw('YEAR(CURDATE()) - lahir_yy >= ?', [request('umur')]);  
    }

    if(request('negeri_lahir')) {
        $query->where('NegeriID', request('negeri_lahir'));
    }

    if(request('kategori')) {
        $query->where('CategoryID', request('kategori'));
    }

    if(request('pangkat')) {
        $query->where('OperasiID', request('pangkat'));
    }

$newitem = $query->get();

return response($newitem);
```

This is the route:

```
 Route::resource('carian_anugerah', 'Modul\CarianAnugerahController');
 Route::post('/search-calon', 'Modul\CarianAnugerahController@search');
```

I can get the value but it doesn't display in table..it shows the output in json format in a white page..

example output..in browser.

[image: example output in browser]

What is missing in the ajax code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should remove `form` `action` and `method`. Because if you are submitting form via `ajax` you dont need `action` and `method`. Due to `action` and `method` your form is submitting like normal post of form data and that`s why you are receiving output on browser.

```
 {!! Form::open() !!}
 {{ csrf_field() }}
 //Form for filter here...

 {{ Form::submit('Cari', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'id' =>'search']) }}
 {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Try these changes and see if you are getting desired result. And make ajax call with `post`, your `search-calon` route is `POST`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#search').on('click', function(){

$.post("{{ URL::to('search-calon') }}",function(data){

    $.each(data, function(i, value){

        var tr =$("<tr/>");
          tr.append($("<td/>",{
              text : value.name
          }))
          $('#calon_anugerah').append(tr);
    });
})
})
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, I just noticed about the form method. It invoke the method controller than ajax function. thank you

Comment: @joun You are Welcome.